# How to prevent log output from Apache Commons Exec

Tags: java, jboss, apache-commons-exec

I am using Apache Commons Exec on a web application in JBoss 4.2.3. Whenever I call Apache Exec it outputs all the console output in the log and this is a lot of output and it could easily fill in my logs in a production environment. How can I prevent this log from printing and only show error logs?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your log4j.properties file for your web app add a line that looks something like this following...

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.exec=ERROR
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the file size too ? It can still reach a big size in the further future.

Answer (score 7):

You can also disable the stdout/stderr/stdin streams from the process by supplying it null streams. This way you don't need to fiddle with the logging levels if you really have no use for the output.

```
executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(null, null, null));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable logging on application server level. Just add to `jboss-log4j.xml` such line:

```
<category name="org.apache.commons.exec">
  <priority value="ERROR"/>
</category>
```